# Zxing issue with the portrait mode for the Samsung Galaxy Note

Tags: android, zxing, galaxy

I'm working onto an application which can scan QRCode and I want to have the two screen modes (portrait and landscape) implemented. I'm using the code provided by Google to turn correctly my camera : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29 
 It's work fine with a phone (Motorola Razr) and with a tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab) in both screen mode. But with the Samsung Galaxy Note, I have lines on the screen when I am in portrait mode as you can see in the picture displayed below (it works fine in landscape mode).[image]

Does someone had already encountered and corrected this issue? Or maybe does someone have a lead that I can follow to solve my problem?

Thanks,
seb